# Error in subsetting with $ immediately after a function in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, dplyr

I could subset a single column with the following syntax for functions that return `data.frame` or `list`:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(mtcars, disp > 400)$mpg
# [1] 10.4 10.4 14.7
```

But this causes the following error when used in a pipe (`%>%`):

```
mtcars %>% filter(disp > 400)$mpg
# Error in .$filter(disp > 400) : 
#   3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2
```

I would like to know why `$` does not work when used in pipe like the above example.

Comment: There is also the `pull` function of dplyr which you can use to extract a column as a vector

Comment: @Sotos, this is helpful, a new function for me.

Comment: I'm using `pull` as well recently, but before I used to do `(mtcars %>% filter(disp > 400))$mpg`

Comment: Since this is a pipe, why can't `mtcars %>% filter(disp > 400) %>% .$mpg` this be done

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was running your first command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have figured out the reason.

When I call `filter(mtcars, disp > 400)$mpg`, what actually happen is:

```
`$`(filter(mtcars, disp > 400), mpg)
# [1] 10.4 10.4 14.7
```

Similarly, `mtcars %>% filter(disp > 400)$mpg` is interpreted as:

```
`$`(mtcars, filter(disp > 400), mpg)
```

, because lhs of `%>%` will be the first argument of the function at rhs. This reproduced the same error that `$` requires 2 args while 3 were supplied.

```
# Error in mtcars$filter(disp > 400) : 
#   3 arguments passed to '$' which requires 2
```

The error message also verified the above speculation. `mtcars` is used as the data.frame name and `filter(disp > 400)`is treated as a column name:  **`mtcars$filter(disp > 400)`**.